# VS2017 MSB4057 The target "CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-service-fabric

When VS2017 was used to create a stateful solution, producing the standard boilerplate code, the resulting two projects have two different MSBuild versions.
The application uses MSBuild version 1.5.0.
The service uses MSBuild version 1.6.0 (the current "latest").

If I run the solution this way, it runs fine on my local Service Fabric cluster.

But when after I use NuGet to update the application's MSBuild to 1.6.0 (so both application and server projects use the same), the following errors occur.

---

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The OutputPath property is not set for project 'gt_strd5.sfproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  P follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has belatform='x64'.  This error may also appear if some other project is trying toen unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform. gt_strd5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 737 

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB4057 The target "CreateManifestResourceNames" does not exist in the project. gt_strd5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2630
```

---

Answer (score 2):

I found that after the change, some references in the application's project file continued to reference MSBuild 1.5.0. In my case, the gt_strd5.sfproj file contained four references which needed to be updated from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0. See the snippets from the XML below.

```
Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.**MSBuild.1.5.0**\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.**MSBuild.1.5.0**\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')"
.....
Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.**MSBuild.1.5.0**\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.**MSBuild.1.5.0**\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')"
```

To verify this, I went back a couple times and was able to reproduce both the issue and this solution.

Hope it saves someone else some time.
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error into PCF control.

Run Developer Command Prompt VS2017/ VS2019

a) Remove white space from your folder like **Test%20-%20PCFs** (source control generated name) should be **TestPCFs**

b) Go to pcf project folder from cmd line & run **msbuild /t:restore**

b) Go to cds project folder from cmd line & run **msbuild /t:restore**

c) On cds project folder, run **msbuild**

d) For release deployment run msbuild **/p:configuration=Release**

***For other types of projects***

a) Remove white space from your folder name

b) run **msbuild /t:restore**

c) run **msbuild**